# Hashset -making objects same after creation of Set

Tags: java, collections

IF we add two different objects(mutable) in HashSet and after that change the value of the objects by calling setter(making them same), the size remains 2 of the hashSet

I am not able to understand the reason for the same :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setName("Amit");
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setName("Jitender");
        Set<Person> hashSet = new HashSet<Person>();
        hashSet.add(e);
        hashSet.add(e1);
        // size of set is >>2
        System.out.println("size of set is >>" + hashSet.size());
        e1.setName("Amit");
        // updated size of set is >>2
        System.out.println("updated size of set is >>" + hashSet.size());
}
```

Employee class is :

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Employee e = (Employee) obj;
        return this.name.equals(e.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashSet` is not intended to react to changes in the objects it contains. In fact, the documentation warns against adding mutable objects to a set and modifying them.

From the [`Set` interface documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

( Another point is that `HashSet` uses the members' `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, which means that if you did not implement those methods for your `Employee`, two `Employee`s will not be equal unless they are two references to the same `Employee` object. ) In your edit you show that you implemented that.

On a practical "what happens if I do this anyway?" note, if you look at the [source code of `HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) (b/c a `HashSet` is implemented as a `HashMap` that maps the entries you insert to a dummy object) you can see that the size is only updated when you add and remove variables, and that even when the table is rehashed to increase the capacity, there are no equality checks, **so your duplicate objects will stay in that set that you just broke by doing what you shouldn't have been doing in the first place.**

Comment: thanks for the clarification...one more thing...as the doc says "A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element"......does that mean, its not a good idea or a exception(as i tried to add it, and it does not give any exception)

Comment: It just said that adding a set to itself is a bad idea, and it will break the set. It will not throw an exception or raise an error -- it just won't function correctly.

Comment: And what happens when you try to remove those duplicate objects?

Answer (score 3):

And how did you define the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in the `Employee` class?. Besides, nothing in the contract of a `HashSet` specifies what to do if two mutable objects in the set suddenly have the same hash, you can't assume that either one of them is automatically removed from the set.

Also, be aware of this [note](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) from the documentation of `Set`:

> Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

Answer (score 0):

`size()` returns number of elements in the set. Since you don't alter the set by calling `e1.setName()` the size of the set remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You added 2 different objects to the Set. They are different objects even if their value is same.

Answer (score 0):

They were created using two different instances of Employee.class. So even if they have the same value for property name, they are still different objects. Unless of course hash and equals are overridden in the Employee.class such that equality is based on propery name.