# distinct() method not returning distinct elements for stream of HashSet elements

Tags: java, java-8

Let say I have Employee class with properly overridden equals and hashcode method.

```
public class Employee {

private int eno;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    System.out.println("hashcode called");
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + eno;
    result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("equals called");
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (eno != other.eno)
        return false;
    if (firstName == null) {
        if (other.firstName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
        return false;
    if (lastName == null) {
        if (other.lastName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Testing class as below

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Karan", "Mehara");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Rajesh", "Shukla");

        Set<Employee> emps= new HashSet<>();
        emps.add(e1);
        emps.add(e2);
        System.out.println(emps);

        // No such requirement just for testing purpose modifying 
        e2.setEno(1);
        e2.setFirstName("Karan");
        e2.setLastName("Mehara");

        System.out.println(emps);

        emps.stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

The output of the above program is:

[Employee [eno=1, firstName=Karan, lastName=Mehara], Employee [eno=2, firstName=Rajesh, lastName=Shukla]]

[Employee [eno=1, firstName=Karan, lastName=Mehara], Employee [eno=1, firstName=Karan, lastName=Mehara]]

**Employee [eno=1, firstName=Karan, lastName=Mehara]**

**Employee [eno=1, firstName=Karan, lastName=Mehara]**

Why distinct() method return duplicate elements??

According to equals() and hashcode() method of employee class both objects are the same.

I have observed that when I call distinct() method equals() and hashcode() method **won't get a call** for a stream of **Set implementation** but it **get a call** for a stream of **List implementation**.

As per JavaDoc says 
distinct() Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements **(according to Object.equals(Object))** of this stream.

```
/**
     * Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to
     * {@link Object#equals(Object)}) of this stream.
     *
     * <p>For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable
     * (for duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter
     * order is preserved.)  For unordered streams, no stability guarantees
     * are made.
     *
     * <p>This is a <a href="package-summary.html#StreamOps">stateful
     * intermediate operation</a>.
     *
     * @apiNote
     * Preserving stability for {@code distinct()} in parallel pipelines is
     * relatively expensive (requires that the operation act as a full barrier,
     * with substantial buffering overhead), and stability is often not needed.
     * Using an unordered stream source (such as {@link #generate(Supplier)})
     * or removing the ordering constraint with {@link #unordered()} may result
     * in significantly more efficient execution for {@code distinct()} in parallel
     * pipelines, if the semantics of your situation permit.  If consistency
     * with encounter order is required, and you are experiencing poor performance
     * or memory utilization with {@code distinct()} in parallel pipelines,
     * switching to sequential execution with {@link #sequential()} may improve
     * performance.
     *
     * @return the new stream
     */
    Stream<T> distinct();
```

Comment: @MirkoAlicastro You can compare primitives (such as `int`, which is the type of `eno`), it's won't compare them by ref but by value.

Comment: @MirkoAlicastro I have given above example for testing purpose only. My question is why hashCode and equal method wont call If i call distinct () method.

Comment: I've read wrong, i thought they both were employee objects

Comment: Even stranger, `System.out.println(e1.equals(e2));` return `true` right before the `Stream` part

Comment: The answer is that you are doing a wrong operation: you are editing an object, inserted in a hashmap. You shouldn't modify the fields used by the hashcode when the object is inserted. You should remove it, modify it, and then re-inserting it, in order to give it the right position in the hashmap

Comment: @GBlodgett Yes, its return true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442499/hashset-making-objects-same-after-creation-of-set. The result of modifying an object after adding it to a `HashSet` is unspecified, so `.stream().distinct()` can do pretty much anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hashset -making objects same after creation of Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442499/hashset-making-objects-same-after-creation-of-set)

Comment: @MirkoAlicastro Yes you are right i have just doing to getting understanding of distinct method. But if set contains two objects and according to equal and hashcode they are equal. And as java doc said it uses equal and hashcode so why it not call equal and hashcode if i call distinct method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Set` is [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to be "A collection that contains no duplicate elements". So a `Stream`'s `distinct`-method of a `Set` is most likely be implemented to do nothing at all because it's already garantueed that values are unique.

What you've did is explicitly mentioned in the Javadoc:

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.